# How to use array for data in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create a bar chart using ChartJs.

I have three arrays array_label,array_present & array_absent.These arrays have data that come from the database through ajax.

But still, the graph is not created

Note: It works perfectly when I enter static data in an array

Server side technology:PHP

```
var areaChartData = {
  labels: array_label,
  datasets: [
    {
      label               : 'Present',
      fillColor           : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      strokeColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
      pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      data                : array_present
    },
    {
      label               : 'Absent',
      fillColor           : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
      strokeColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
      pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
      pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
      pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
      data                : array_absent
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you tried to compare ajax data result within html with statically added values data +html. You are probably missing something in ajax created html+data.

Comment: @Nezir The data that comes through ajax is perfect.

Comment: I would check for js errors shown in the browser (developer tools)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  label : 'test',
  fillColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
  strokeColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
  pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
  pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
  pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
  pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
  data: [45,49, 60, 81, 76, 55, 40]
},
```